# Is the icon-hd missing in Font-awesome 4.5?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I saw some icons in a website that I wanted to use, as seen in this screenshot:

[image: icon-eye and icon-hd]

I downloaded and installed the 4.5.0 .otf font and tried to copy+paste the icons directly to Photoshop. The eye icon was called "fa-eye" and I could easily find in the [Font-awesome Cheatsheet](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/). The second icon I could not find in the list.

In the website where I found it, the icon is inserted using a CSS::before pseudo-element (so I can't select and copy the character directly). This part of the code is as follows:

```css
.icon-eye:before {
        content: "\e607";
    }
.icon-hd:before {
        content: "\e604";
    }
```

```html
<li class="icon-eye">text</li>
<li class="icon-hd">more text</li>
```

Why is this second icon not in the Cheatsheet for 4.5.0? Where can I find it and what is it called?

Comment: Since they're not using the Font Awesome syntax, what makes you think it's Font Awesome?

Comment: because of <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> in the head and the eye icon is Font-awesome. There are other icons in the page as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That icon *might* be part of Fort Awesome's [Material Design icon set](https://fortawesome.com/sets/material-design) (which is by the same guy who makes the Font Awesome icon set), although it doesn't quite look the same:

> [image: HD Icon]

This isn't free, however, and is available through their $49/year *Starter* package.

As Paulie_D has pointed out in the comments, the `icon-*` syntax is old and no longer used by Font Awesome. This is probably part of some other icon set which uses a very similar *eye* icon (if not the same one copied from Font Awesome).

Font Awesome's GitHub repository does have [a requests for a *hd* icon](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/518) which dates back to 2012, but this has yet to be implemented in Font Awesome itself (if it ever will).

Comment: the HD icon I mentioned is not square, and the letters don't look the same. The eye is from the standard set.

Comment: @Luciano yep, as I said, it doesn't quite look the same. What you've found isn't a Font Awesome or Fort Awesome icon and has thus been created by someone else.

Comment: You know what? it is actually another font. Somewhere buried in the rest of the code there was a @font-face, a font with some of the glyphs identical to Font Awesome. Huge facepalm here for overlooking this.